# Cannot import key file with sn.exe?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I get the following error when I compile my project:

```
Cannot import the following key file: MyKey.pfx. 
The key file may be password protected. 
To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the 
certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: 
VS_KEY_A46F65B4A8A780C7
```

I tried to install the key with the Strong Naming Tool (sn.exe) by starting up the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" shortcut and entering the following text:

```
sn –i “C:\MyKey.pfx” VS_KEY_A46F65B4A8A780C7
```

(and yes, the file is in the C:\ directory)

Executing the command only results in a list of available commands (the same you get when you enter "sn -h").

Do I miss something here?

Unfortunately, Google didn't help me with my problem, so I hope the stackoverflow community will. ;)

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I found the solution:
In the project properties, I had to re-enter the password for the .pfx file.
I still have no idea why, but it solved the compiling error.

Hope this helps anyone who might run into the same problem.